# Fazendo JOIN no Pandas com intervalos de tempo

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, numpy

Tenho os seguintes dataframes:

*df_equip*

| Equipamento | Data | Operador |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2022-01-03 12:09:00 | NaN |
| X | 2022-01-03 12:19:00 | NaN |
| X | 2022-01-03 12:29:00 | NaN |
| X | 2022-01-03 13:19:00 | NaN |
| Y | 2022-01-03 12:13:00 | NaN |
| Y | 2022-01-03 12:34:00 | NaN |
| X | 2022-01-03 13:49:00 | NaN |
| X | 2022-01-03 14:49:00 | NaN |
| X | 2022-01-03 15:29:00 | NaN |
| X | 2022-01-03 18:49:00 | NaN |

*df_login*

| Operador | Status | Data | Equipamento |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | Login | 2022-01-03 12:10:00 | X |
| A02 | Login | 2022-01-03 12:11:00 | Y |
| A02 | Logout | 2022-01-03 12:14:32 | Y |
| A01 | Logout | 2022-01-03 13:15:00 | X |
| A03 | Login | 2022-01-03 14:10:00 | X |
| A03 | Logout | 2022-01-03 16:10:00 | X |

Eu preciso inserir na *df_equip['Operador']* o código relacionado ao operador contido em *df_login['Operador']* levando em consideração o tempo em que ele está com o login ativo. Sendo que a coluna DATA dos dois dataframes contém valores distintos.
Gostaria de saber se há algum jeito de usar esse intervalo de tempo entre login e logout para fazer o JOIN entre as duas tabelas e inserir o valor que eu preciso.
PS: O equipamento pode estar ligado sem nenhum operador logado

Comment: GusThePraga, conseguiu verificar se minha resposta atendeu a sua pergunta? Se sim, considere [aceita-la](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/30452) :)

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente ainda não existe uma forma nativa no pandas para unir 2 DataFrames por um intervalo de datas.

Para o seu problema eu resolveria isso com os seguintes passos:

1. Transformar as colunas **Data** para o tipo datetime com `to_datetime`
2. Remover a coluna **Operador** do df_equip com o `drop`
3. Transformar o **Status** em colunas com a fução `pivot`
4. Unir os DFs com `.merge` pela coluna **Equipamento**
5. Criar coluna dummy para saber quem estava loggado no momento com `.between`
6. Mudar para NaN o **Operador** quando ele não estava logado com `mask`
7. E remover os itens duplicados com `.drop_duplicates`, `.sort_values` e `.drop`

Segue o código:

```
df_equip['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df_equip['Data'])
df_login['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df_login['Data'])

df_equip.drop(columns=['Operador'], inplace=True)

df_login = df_login.pivot(index=['Operador', 'Equipamento'], columns='Status', values='Data').reset_index()

new_df = df_equip.merge(df_login, on = 'Equipamento', how = 'left')

new_df['is_logged'] = new_df['Data'].between(new_df['Login'], new_df['Logout'])

new_df = (
     new_df.sort_values('Operador')
    .drop_duplicates(['Equipamento', 'Data'])
    .drop(columns=['Login', 'Logout', 'is_logged'])
    .sort_values('Data')
)

new_df.head(10)
#saida:
    Equipamento Data                Operador
0   X           2022-01-03 12:09:00 NaN
8   Y           2022-01-03 12:13:00 A02
2   X           2022-01-03 12:19:00 A01
4   X           2022-01-03 12:29:00 A01
9   Y           2022-01-03 12:34:00 NaN
6   X           2022-01-03 13:19:00 NaN
10  X           2022-01-03 13:49:00 NaN
13  X           2022-01-03 14:49:00 A03
15  X           2022-01-03 15:29:00 A03
16  X           2022-01-03 18:49:00 NaN
```